# C# comma separated string adds extra ending comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, list, arraylist

I pass a string of values from form to MVC5 Controller and save items in one field in database using the C#.

The `string[]CarNotes` is accessed with the actionresult in controller and manipulated as below:

```
string selection = "";
                if (CarNotes != null && CarNotes.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in CarNotes)
                    {
                        selection += s + ", ";
                    }
                }
```

I then save the contents of selection in the assigned database field.  This works fine. The only problem is that it adds an extra ',' at the end of the list. How can I prevent this extra ','.  Thanks

Comment: Use the [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method - `string value = String.Join(", ", CarNotes);`

Comment: `selection += ( selection == "" ? "" : ", " ) + s;` should do it, though `String.Join` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also try using string.join...

```
var selection = String.Join(", ", CarNodes);
```

more info here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JeremyThompson really how's it a rip off when i answered it first?? lol

Comment: @JeremyThompson r u sure that Stephen Muecke is the only one here who knows about `String.Join`?

Comment: This answer was the exact thought I had when I read the title of the question, would not call it a rip-off. Even if it were, I doubt that Steven would care or he would have posted it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Always use a StringBuilder when you're concatenating strings:

```
StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder();
if (CarNotes != null && CarNotes.Length > 0)
{
   foreach (string s in CarNotes)
   {
      selection.Append(s);
      selection.Append(", ");
   }
}
//Trim the ending space, then trim the ending comma
return selection.ToString().TrimEnd().TrimEnd(',');
```

---

Alternatively you could use `Substring`:

```
if (selection.EndsWith(", "))
{
    selection = selection.Substring(0, selection.Length - 2);
}
```

Or `Remove`:

```
if (selection.EndsWith(", "))
{
    selection = selection.Remove(selection.Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Is there any benefits of explicit `StringBuilder` usage and removing ending separator, comparing to implicit `StringBuilder` usage with `String.Join`?

Comment: You could also use the `AppendFormat($"{s}, ")` method

Answer (score 0):

aside from String.Join, you can also use aggregate (linq, aka reduce in functional programming)

```
var selection = CarNotes.Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j);
```